# Properties of "Digit Sum Root"?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $x$ be a base $k$ number with digits: $d_1 d_2 \cdots d_n$

(This implies the value of $x$ is $ d_1k^{n-1} +d_2k^{n-2} + \dots +d_{n-1}k+ d_n$)

We define $R(x)$ to be the "digit sum root":

If $x < k$, $R(x) = x$

Otherwise $R(x) = R(d_1 + d_2 + \dots + d_n)$

That is, we keep adding up the digits until we have a single digit. (all in base k)

What interesting properties does the function $R(x)$ have?  For example, what can we say about $R(x + y)$? or $R(xy)$? and so on?  How can we calculate $R$ efficiently for large $x$?

Comment: It has all the nice properties one might desire, and that we are perhaps familiar with in the case $k=10$. Hint: $x\equiv R(x)\pmod{k-1}$.

Comment: Look on Wikipedia under "digital root": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root.

Comment: I suspect you will have something like $\varphi(x)=\displaystyle\max_{n\leq x}R(n)=O(\ln x)$

Comment: @AndréNicolas - looking at base 10, one has zero divisors $(3 \times 3 = 9)$. If one were to choose base 8 or base 12 this would not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\rm\ R(x)\equiv x\pmod{k\!-\!1}.\:$ It's the radix $\rm\,k\,$ analog of casting out $9$'s for radix $10$ (decimal).

**Remark** $\ $ You can find much further discussion in [prior posts on casting nines.](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+casting)